# Unrecognized selector sent to instance when calling back button programmatically

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I'm viewing a detail view when clicking on a record from the table.  When I call the back button from the detail view using

```
- (IBAction)loadDispensary 
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I get the unrecognized selector error.

I've tried pushing the the detail controller the following two ways.

```
Push type 1
detailViewController *detailView = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailView"];
detailView.strain = self.selectedStrain;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];

Push type 2
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"detailSegue" sender: self];
//Set the strain on the prepareForSegue
```

Comment: how the button is connected? can u show the code?

Comment: Also show the specific error string in it's entirety (what selector, what object?)

Comment: @samfisher It was how the button was wired up, if you put that as the answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: @samfisher Your answer disappeared. . .

Comment: @Jhorra just posted another version of same answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how the button is connected? can u show the code? perhaps you might have not properly linked the button to the IBAction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be trying to pop a view controller that is already popped.  If you have a UINavigationController and you "Push" a view controller through a segue, the back button that is displayed at the top left of the screen is already configured.  You should not have to put one there yourself.  If you programmitically place a button in the left bar button position it will display in place of the UINavigation's button.

Try removing the button and allowing the UINavigationController to manage going back and see if that works better.

Comment: There was previously an answer that I had marked accepted, I had changed the name of the method the button was pointed to.

Comment: That's strange.  Oh well at least you found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Someone had asked me to paste the full error code and when I went to do that I saw that the method the button was pointed to was no longer there, so it was trying to call a method that didn't exist.